# html meta charset not working: get ISO-8859-1 while set UTF-8

Tags: html, jsp, character-encoding

At the head of my page, i have the following code:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

but i got the following response header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Length: 1885
Date: Wed, 07 Oct 2015 03:02:50 GMT
```

And my page shows æ­£åœ¨ä¸Žå…¬ä¼—å·å¯¹è¯ instead of Chinese.

Do u know why?

---

Update:

I just learned something of document encoding(in browser): The simplified priority for determining document encoding (in browser) is: (1) browser setting, (2) byte order mark (browser is able to determine encoding on its own), (3) HTTP header, (4) meta tag, (5) best guess.

I guess charset property of meta tag doesn't effect HTTP header.

then what is confusing for me is what effect HTTP header. And how can i set charset = utf-8 in HTTP header?

============================ attach Codes==========================

Below is code of HEAD in JSP page:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE" />
        <title>微信公众号</title>
        <!--讨论区滚动条begin-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%= basePath %>Resource/css/jscrollpane1.css" />
        <script src="<%= basePath %>Resource/js/common/jquery-1.8.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <!-- the mousewheel plugin -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= basePath %>Resource/js/common/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
        <!-- the jScrollPane script -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= basePath %>Resource/js/common/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= basePath %>Resource/js/common/scroll-startstop.events.jquery.js"></script>
        <!--讨论区滚动条end-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= basePath %>Resource/js/front/talk.js"></script>
    </head>
```

Servlet code is simply:

```
@WebServlet(name = "InitTalkServlet")
public class InitTalkServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request,response);
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        //        设置编码
        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

//        页面跳转
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/JSP/FRONT/talk.jsp").forward(request,response);
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't be. Is there any other meta tag overriding this line?

Comment: @Raptor no overriding meta tag, i double checked.

Comment: can you post the code for the document? at least the first quarter or half of the page?

Comment: Also, the character encoding can be set by PHP, .htaccess, and several other ways. Most likely there's an error on your page or it's being overridden. http://www.w3.org/International/O-HTTP-charset

Comment: @Michael_B i posted the relative code. And i use JSP, i think, it doesn't override character encoding.

Comment: The `meta` element looks perfect, and it's positioned in the right place. Not that it should make a difference, but have you tried the alternative form: `<meta charset="utf-8">` ?

Comment: @Michael_B i think they are equivalent.

Comment: They are equivalent. But I suggested testing the alternative in case they are being processed differently.

Answer (score 1):

I find a resolution:

> Open the JSP file with Sublime, File | Save with Encoding | UTF-8 with
>   BOM.

but i still don't know why it works.